# Errors involving expected types

Tags: haskell

The following piece of code (which is taken from Graham Hutton's "Programming in Haskell" (Chapter 9))

```
:{
Prelude| data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
Prelude| instance Show Op where
Prelude|    show Add = "+"
Prelude|    show Sub = "-"
Prelude|    show Mul = "*"
Prelude|    show Div = "/"
Prelude| valid :: Op -> Int -> Int -> Bool
Prelude| valid Add _ _ = True
Prelude| valid Sub x y = x > y
Prelude| valid Mul _ _ = True
Prelude| valid Div x y = x `mod` y == 0
Prelude| apply :: Op -> Int -> Int -> Int
Prelude| apply Add x y = x + y
Prelude| apply Sub x y = x - y
Prelude| apply Mul x y = x * y
Prelude| apply Div x y = x `div` y
Prelude| data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr
Prelude| instance Show Expr where
Prelude|       show (Val n) = n
Prelude|       show (App o l r) = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r 
Prelude|                          where
Prelude|                             brak (Val n ) = show n
Prelude|                             brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
Prelude| :}
```

generates these errors:

```
<interactive>:455:22: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: Int
• In the expression: n
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’: Prelude.show (Val n) = n
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show Expr’

<interactive>:456:26: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘brak l’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’:
      Prelude.show (App o l r)
        = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
        where
            brak (Val n) = show n
            brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:456:36: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r

<interactive>:456:41: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’ with actual type ‘Op’
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘o’
  In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’

<interactive>:456:46: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘brak r’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r

<interactive>:458:50: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘n’
  In the expression: show n
  In an equation for ‘brak’: brak (Val n) = show n

<interactive>:459:38: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
• In the expression: "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
  In an equation for ‘brak’: brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’:
      Prelude.show (App o l r)
        = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
        where
            brak (Val n) = show n
            brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:459:45: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e ++ ")"’
  In the expression: "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:459:50: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’
              with actual type ‘Expr’
  NB: ‘Expr’ is defined at <interactive>:453:1-38
      ‘Ghci41.Expr’ is defined at <interactive>:246:1-35
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘e’
  In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e ++ ")"’
```

I do not understand what has gone wrong. Can anyone help? Do I need to declare the type of `n` to be a String, in order to deal with the first error? What are the other error reports pointing out?

If I see error reports like these particular ones, what would be a good strategy for me to employ in order to avoid them?

---

Edit:

I have tried out the code in the answer below, but I receive the following errors:

```
   <interactive>:520:20: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: Int
• In the expression: show n
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’: Prelude.show (Val n) = show n
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show Expr’

<interactive>:520:25: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘n’
  In the expression: show n
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’: Prelude.show (Val n) = show n

<interactive>:521:24: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘brak l’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’:
      Prelude.show (App o l r)
        = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
        where
            brak (Val n) = show n
            brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:521:34: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r

<interactive>:521:39: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’ with actual type ‘Op’
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘o’
  In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’

<interactive>:521:44: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘brak r’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show o ++ brak r’
  In the expression: brak l ++ show o ++ brak r

<interactive>:522:34: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘n’
  In the expression: show n
  In an equation for ‘brak’: brak (Val n) = show n

<interactive>:523:23: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
• In the expression: "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
  In an equation for ‘brak’: brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
  In an equation for ‘Prelude.show’:
      Prelude.show (App o l r)
        = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r
        where
            brak (Val n) = show n
            brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:523:30: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e ++ ")"’
  In the expression: "(" ++ show e ++ ")"

<interactive>:523:35: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Ghci41.Expr’
              with actual type ‘Expr’
  NB: ‘Expr’ is defined at <interactive>:518:1-38
      ‘Ghci41.Expr’ is defined at <interactive>:246:1-35
• In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘e’
  In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show e ++ ")"’
```

Comment: *please* stop pasting code in ghci as your way of developing! It hurts me to watch! Get a proper editor and load the file with `:load` or command line argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only error I spot here is that `n` is an `Int`, and thus you need to use `show` to convert that to a `String`:

```
instance Show Expr where
    show (Val n) = show n
    show (App o l r) = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r 
        where brak (Val n) = show n
              brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
```

Furthermore you do not show the type of `Op`, but this should be a type that is an instance of [**`Show`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) as well, so you should define a `instance Show Op`.

For example:

```
Prelude> data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
Prelude> :{
Prelude| instance Show Op where
Prelude|     show Add = "+"
Prelude|     show Sub = "-"
Prelude|     show Mul = "*"
Prelude|     show Div = "/"
Prelude| :}
Prelude> data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr
Prelude> :{
Prelude| instance Show Expr where
Prelude|     show (Val n) = show n
Prelude|     show (App o l r) = brak l ++ show o ++ brak r 
Prelude|         where brak (Val n) = show n
Prelude|               brak e = "(" ++ show e ++ ")"
Prelude| :}
```

and then we can query it like:

```
Prelude> show (App Mul (Val 3) (App Add (Val 3) (Val 2)))
"3*(3+2)"
```

Comment: The code in your answer produces `<interactive>:478:14: error: parse error on input ‘brak’`. How come?

Comment: @user65526: sorry, there was some problem with the indentation when pasting this.

Comment: How do you know when `where` requires a new line in Haskell (as in the second occurrence of `where` in your code), and when `where` can be at the end of a line (as in the first occurrence of `where` in the code above)? So whenever `where` starts a new line it must be indented? And then the next line after must be indented further, as with `brak e`?

Comment: @user65526: `where` does not requires a new line. THe idea is that Haskell is a language that uses spacing as a way to define a scope, so since we have two clauses for `brak`, we need to indent it at the same level.

Comment: The code you provided above still produces a few of the error messages I wrote in my question.

Comment: @user65526: it looks as if you defined it as `data Expr = Val Expr | App Op Expr Expr`, not as  `data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr`, or as said before, but I can not check, did not create an instance of `Show` for `Op`.

Comment: I have the following instance for `Op` (where each occurrence of lower case `show` is on a separate line, and indented with respect to `instance`):  `instance Show Op where
show Add = "+"
show Sub = "-"
show Mul = "*"
show Div = "/"`

Comment: @user65526: well I ran this on the shell, see above.

Comment: I tried out the code in your answer, and receive the errors which I have just put under 'Edit' in my question.

Comment: @user65526: it looks like you defined a `show` *not* in an `instance Show` block, and thus have *overwritten* the `show` function. Probably you better restart a session